# Migrating MS SQL to MySQL using MySQL Workbench causes a permission error

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, database-migration

I have been working on this all day and now I'm stuck, so hopefully someone out there can help me :)

The challenge.

Migrate data from MS SQL to MySQL.

The MS SQL I received as a bak file, which I restored using SQL server management studio on a PC with Windows 7 Home edition.

I have created a source MySQL database on a webserver, running LAMP.

The solution (maybe)
I'm currently trying to convert the database, initially just one table for testing, using MySQL Workbench with the database->migrate wizard, but now I'm stuck at the Bulk Data Transfer. I would expect this step to create the table in my MySQL database and transfer the data, but that never happens.

For the source I choose Connection Method = ODBC (native)
No problems connecting to the source and destination databases

I choose to keep schema info as table prefix, so imported tables look like: database.dbo_table_name

Migration step succeeds (migrate selected objects & Generate SQL Create Statements)

The Create statements look like this if I don't edit them
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'restored_database_name'.'dbo_table_name' … I think the 'restored_database_name' part causes a permission error. It does if I type this in the SQL tab directly in phpMyAdmin. Therefore I change it to:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'dbo_table_name' …

Also per default this is part of the SQL:
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS 'restored_database_name';
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS 'restored_database_name …
I think this also causes some permission issues, so I commented these out.

In the next step I uncheck the 'Create schema in target RDBMS' since I don't think I want this.

The problem:
Nothing interesting for the next steps, but then at the "Bulk data Transfer" I get this error:
ERROR: 'restored_database_name'. 'dbo_database_name': mysql_stmt_prepare: SELECT command denied to user 'mysql_user_name'@host' for table 'dbo_database_table_name.
Finished copying 0 rows.

I think the error is somehow related to permissions on the destination database. I wonder if it is possible to make sql file, not just with the create table commands, but also with INSERT commands so I could just take the sql and import it using command line or phpmyadmin.

I'm using Workbench 5.2 CE

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I've seen that you have made your way into the Workbench's Migration Wizard. Maybe you're just missing something so I suggest you to review this blog so you can verify your steps: [How-To: Guide to Database Migration from Microsoft SQL Server using MySQL Workbench](http://mysqlworkbench.org/?p=1350).

Unfortunately you can't use the Migration Wizard data copy command line utility to generate the SQL file with all the inserts, but I'm pretty sure you can get this from MS SQL Server Management Studio and it should pretty much work for MySQL without modifications (or with minor modifications).